# visual studios express 2013 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Every time that i make a new program i get this error when compiling, formerly i used 2012 and never had this problem but now i see this every time:

**Error:**

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
"public: __cdecl lonework::App::App(void)" (??0App@lonework@@Q$AAA@XZ)
referenced in function "public: void __thiscall <lambda_b6bf150325cab1ba448790bcac21fea0>::operator()(class Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams ^)
const " (??R<lambda_b6bf150325cab1ba448790bcac21fea0>@@QBEXP$AAVApplicationInitializationCallbackParams@Xaml@UI@Windows@@@Z)    C:\Users\Logan\Documents\Visual Studio 
    2013\Projects\lonework\lonework\lonework.Windows\XamlTypeInfo.g.obj lonework.Windows
```

**The code currently working on:**

```
#include <pch.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int yes();
int no();

int main()
{
    char choice;
    printf("Think of a number between one and ten\n");
    Sleep(2000);
    printf("Got it yet?\n Y/N ");
    scanf_s("%c", &choice,1);
    if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
    {
        printf("That's good");
        yes();
    }
    else if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N')
    {
        printf("Are you really that slow");
        no();
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int yes()
{
    printf("Good for you, keep thinking about it...\n");
    printf("Now think of another one, a different one\n Got it?\n I'll assume yes, sounds good.\n     Now I'll tell you your number.\n");
    printf("...\n");
    Sleep(2000);
    printf("...\n");
    Sleep(2000);
    printf("Ahem, 3 and 7");
    return 0;
}
int no()
{
    printf("Alright, back to the top.\n");
    main();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this code you dont need to `include pch.h`, actually there is no such file shipped with VS.

There are two ways to correct this

1.) In VS click

1. Name your project
2. create a new C++ project,
3. select `Win32 Application`,
4. uncheck `precompiled header`,
5. uncheck `Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) checks`,
6. click finish
7. A new project will created, and the cpp file with your project name will be opened.
8. Copy and paste this source code and remove the line `#include <pch.h>`
   Now you can compile and run it.

or

2.)In VS solution containing this project:

1. Right click the Project name inside the solution explorer
2. Click `Properties` Click `C/C++` Tab on the left side
3. Click Precompiled headers
4. On the right side on `Precompiled headers` colume, change from `use` to `Not Using Precompiled Headers`
5. Click apply
6. Now if you are using Visual Studio Community you will have a file
   named '`AssemblyInfo`', remove that file by right clicking it and
   selecting remove
7. Now delete the first line `#include <pch.h>`

   Compile and run it

Actually you are compiling C code in Visual C++, So when ever you create a new project you must un check SDL checks(Security Development Lifecycle)

Another easy way is to create a new `blank C++ project`, on solution explorer right click `source files`. click `add`, click `new item`, select `C++ File`, now paste the code in it and run it.This is the most easy way if you are begining new project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you select an empty project or a C++ console application and not managed C++ application while creating new project.